# Is the man in the flashbacks really the Man in Black?

Tags: analysis, lost

In [Season 6 E15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Across_the_Sea_%28Lost%29) it is shown that Jacob and the Man in Black are really twin brothers and are raised by the mysterious woman that lives on the Island who grants Jacob the powers of the protector.

However, when Jacob discovers his brother murders their 'mother', he is filled with rage and tosses his brother into the Source of the Island.

What happens here is the question at hand, the Smoke Monster comes out of the Source and begins to take the shape of his brother, implying that they are one in the same, however, his brother's body is still present, and is buried with their 'mother'.

So did this man **become** the Smoke Monster, or did Jacob simply **awaken** the smoke monster, with his rage?

Answer (score 4):

I'm under the impression that ***MIB* and the *Smoke Monster* are one and the same.**

- In the episode [Across the Sea](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Across_the_Sea) *(S6 Ep15)* we learn that the ["Mother"](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Mother)

  > made it so they **can never hurt each other**

  Why would the *Smoke Monster* adhere to this (and look for a *loophole*) if it wasn't Jacob's brother?
- In that same episode we see that ***MIB* is desperate to leave the Island**.

  The *Smoke Monster* has the same wish.

There is a [humorous video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fg1qikMstEA#t=1m38s) where *MIB* and *Jacob* have a frank talk about some of that Island stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I think a little of both.  From the early seasons of *Lost* we see that the smoke monster can take the forms of dead people.  It also learns their memories.  So when it was first released, the first person it did this on was the Man in Black.  We don't know what the smoke monster was like previous to that, but starting there, he had the full memories and form of the Man in Black.  It's possible that since that was its first human form, it became its favorite.

Answer (score 2):

The LOST encyclopedia clearly states that the smoke monster was the result of the fusion of MiB's "soul" or "spirit" with a dark force of evil that was within the cave of light in the heart of the island. Thus, the smoke monster was created when Jacob threw his brother in the cave and did not exist before that. The motivations and personality of the smoke monster were carried over from MiB, however with added powers and perhaps an increased level of "malevolence". It's only natural that MiB as the smoke monster would take his own form from when he was still human.